# Select all grouped by year if not equal to minimum of a column + filtered by joined non-id column

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

MySQL version: 8.x

Given this schema + data:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle (
    id int NOT NULL,
    vin varchar(17) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE ubarequest (
    vehicle_id INT NOT NULL,
    year smallint(4) NOT NULL,
    created date NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES vehicle(id)
);

INSERT INTO vehicle values (1, "AAA");
INSERT INTO vehicle values (2, "BBB");
INSERT INTO vehicle values (3, "AAA");
INSERT INTO vehicle values (4, "CCC");
INSERT INTO vehicle values (5, "AAA");

INSERT INTO ubarequest values (2, 2023, "1999-09-09"); # no; different vin
INSERT INTO ubarequest values (4, 2022, "1999-09-09"); # no; different vin


INSERT INTO ubarequest values (1, 2023, "2023-01-01"); # no; oldest in 23
INSERT INTO ubarequest values (3, 2023, "2023-02-01"); # yes
INSERT INTO ubarequest values (5, 2023, "2023-03-01"); # yes
INSERT INTO ubarequest values (1, 2022, "2023-04-01"); # no; oldest in 22

INSERT INTO ubarequest values (3, 2022, "2023-05-01"); # yes 
INSERT INTO ubarequest values (3, 2022, "2023-06-01"); # yes
INSERT INTO ubarequest values (5, 2022, "2023-07-01"); # yes
INSERT INTO ubarequest values (1, 2022, "2023-08-01"); # yes
```

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c5fe5f/2/0

For a given vin "AAA" I want to select all ubarequests except the respective oldest one per year. So it should take all ubarequests of vehicles with vin 'AAA' (disregarding from which vehicle row) for each year and pick all which are younger than the oldest one.

After experimenting with solutions from similar questions with complex sub-queries I'm confused now if what I came up with (while giving me the expected result) is truly the right query for my needs or if it would fail under certain circumstances:

```
select v.id, u.year, u.created
from ubarequest u
inner join vehicle v
  on u.vehicle_id = v.id
where v.vin = "AAA" and u.created not in (
    select min(created)
    from ubarequest u
    inner join vehicle v on u.vehicle_id = v.id
    where v.vin = "AAA"
    group by u.year)
order by u.created
```

Comment: *# no; oldest in 22* - oldest over the whole data? over the rows with vin="AAA"? over the rows with vehicle_id=3?

Comment: oldest per year and vin. So it should look at all ubarequests of vehicles with vin 'AAA' for each year and pick all which are younger than the oldest one. Hope I worded it more clearly now :)

Comment: @ErgestBasha that is a mistake I will fix, thank you for pointing it out! I'm on MySQL 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.x one way of achieving the desired result would be using [ROW_NUMBER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number).

```
with oldest_ubarequest as (
                  select vin        ,
                         vehicle_id , 
                         year       ,
                         created    ,
                         row_number() over (partition by year order by created asc ) as rn
                  from vehicle v 
                  inner join ubarequest u on u.vehicle_id=v.id
                  where vin='AAA'  
   ) select vin        ,
            vehicle_id ,
            year       ,
            created
     from oldest_ubarequest
     where rn > 1
     order by year,vehicle_id,created;
```

In the subquery we are assigning the oldest value per each year where vin equal to AAA , the number 1 which we will filter out in the end result.

Check the demo[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DzxZxxF2)